# Extraer fecha entre rango de fecha y hora MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tardes necesito su ayuda mi problema es el siguiente,necesito extraer datos de un tabla la cual tiene dos campos llamados "valido-hasta"(tipo date) y un "valido-hasta-time"(tipo time), entonces necesito extraer los datos cuando la fecha y hora actual sea mayor a esos dos campos, intenté probar esto:

```
SELECT *
FROM `promocion`
WHERE ('2019-09-26'AND '19:00:00') >= ( `valido_hasta`AND `valido_hasta_time`)
```

pero no obtuve resultados he buscado en la web pero no encuentro nada que me sirva les agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas:

- Recomponer el formato de `DATETIME`que tendría la fecha y hora actual
- Usar `CONCAT()` para unir tanto: `valido-hasta` y `valido-hasta-time`, dejando un espacio en blanco entre la fecha y la hora.

Para que pases de tener una fecha asi:

```
2019-01-25
```

Y una hora así:

```
13:52:02
```

Al final obtengas una columna combinada en este formato:

```
2019-01-25 13:52:02
```

- Para que sea más dinámico tu query, usa la función `NOW()` que retorna un resultado de tipo `DATETIME`

De tal modo que por *dentro* la comparación luciera un tanto así:

```
//resultado entregado por `NOW()`   comparación     fecha de ejemplo de tu bd, compuesta por las 2 columnas    
    2019-01-25 13:52:02                 >=          2018-01-25 13:52:02
```

Tu consulta podría quedar así:

```
SELECT *
FROM `promocion`
WHERE NOW() >= CONCAT(`valido_hasta`,' ',`valido_hasta_time`);
```

Puedes ocupar:

- `NOW()`
- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Answer (score 1):

La funcion :`CURDATE()` te otorga la fecha actual y la funcion:`curTime()` te otorga la hora actual.

```
SELECT *
  FROM `promocion`
  WHERE `valido_hasta`>=CURDATE()) AND  (curTime()>=`valido_hasta_time`)
```